# How to find all closed issues after specific date in SonarQube5.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

How do I find all the closed issues after a specific date in SonarQube5.1
There is a webservice API to find an open issue after specific date

```
api/issues/search?statuses=OPEN&createdAfter=2015-11-17
```

Do we have something like that for closed issues like closedAfter?

Other way is to query a table  but in SQ5.1 dates are stored in some unix format. How can I convert ISSUE_CLOSE_DATE in the issues table in YYYY-MM-DD format so I can create a query like `select kee,status,resolution where status='CLOSED' and ISSUE_CLOSE_DATE >2015-11-17`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply.Closed issue by default is kept for 30 days.However this can be extended. We keep the closed issue for 90 days in production.The below query can be used to find the closed issue after particular date.

```
select i.kee,i.status,i.resolution,i.SEVERITY,i.tags, to_char(from_tz(CAST(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + ISSUE_CLOSE_DATE/86400000 AS TIMESTAMP), '+00:00') at time zone 'US/PACIFIC', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ISSUE_CLOSE_DATE1 from issues i where i.status='CLOSED' and from_tz(CAST(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + i.ISSUE_CLOSE_DATE/86400000 AS TIMESTAMP), '+00:00') at time zone 'US/PACIFIC' > to_date('2015-11-15','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

I think, Sonar team should develop one WebService to find closed issue after a particular date like below

```
api/issues/search?statuses=CLOSED&closedAfter=2015-11-17
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a reliable way to do this. Open issues are obviously kept in the database, but closed ones get cleaned up (to not bloat the DB). As per documentation on [History and Events](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/History+and+Events): `All closed issues more than 30 days old are deleted`.

So whatever your query on closed issues, the (potentially incomplete) result isn't trustworthy.